# Remove all `at` jobs on boot

Tags: boot, at

Is there a way to delete all unfinished jobs on boot? I tried

```
atrm $(atq | cut -f1)
```

which works perfectly on command line, but it doesn't work on boot. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, specify linux distro that you are using.

Comment: Also, can  you also explain how you're running it 'on boot', where is it being executed, by which user, etc.  Is there any error output in a log file?

Comment: Blind guess: `$PATH` isn't populated where you run it on boot, explicitly saying `/bin/atrm`, `/bin/atq` might help.

Comment: @axvm is about my NAS (MBWE) and and I not sure but I think it is Linux 2.6.24.4, there is only one user "root", and on boot I mean when I turn on the device

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I have tried that already and it didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to delete jobs directly from `AT` spool directory where jobs are stored (this command deletes jobs of user `YOURUSER` only):

```
find /var/spool/atjobs -user YOUR_USER -type f -exec rm {} \;
```